# How to get double the speed from 2 regulated EV3 motors?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g, ev3dev, motor

So I've noticed that if I connect two EV3 motors to one another (with gears), I still get exactly the same maximum speed as if I had a single motor.

So, my question: how can I get twice the power/speed out of two motors?

**Update:** here's an interesting observation: if I get both motors to spin as *unregulated*, I get a much higher speed than if I get them to spin in a pair (e.g., B+C move tank).

**Update 2:** ended up building a differential as per accepted answer:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By adding two motors together with gears, you have doubled the torque the motors provide. Power = torque x speed, so if you don't want the doubled power from the motors to go to the torque component but to the speed component instead, I think you should use a differential and put the motors on both outputs of the differential, and use the input to feed your construction. I haven't tested this out though.

EDIT: Here is a picture I found that shows how 4 motors can be joined into a single output with 5 different motor combinations (and many more different speed combinations):

[image]

Comment: Technically, what you did is just another way of gearing your motors - you increased the speed by adding a gearing reduction. To make my solution you would need to do something like this: http://tinyurl.com/mv2odap . The differentials make sure that any speed difference between the motors does not cause friction, which in your example could happen. Friction would cause the vehicle to stall, or in worst case, cause gears/axles to break due to the enormous torque difference that comes with it. For your purpose you only need 1 differential per wheel, no need to join the 2 wheels with another 1.